# Can I write a universal NFC tag that reads on all phones without installing a specific NFC app?

Tags: android, triggers, nfc, universal

I'm a beginner when it comes to Android development, but I really want to work out what potential NFC holds for a project I'm working on.

I've installed [Trigger](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jwsoft.nfcactionlauncher&hl=en) on my Galaxy S3 and have used it successfully to write a function to an NFC tag that toggles airplane mode on and off on my phone.
The trouble is, I want the tag to be able to do this on ANY phone, not just my own. But whenever I test it on another Android phone, it simply opens the Google Play Store and requests download of Trigger.

I've read through [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23546481/read-nfc-tag-without-specific-application) already, which explains the requirements for reading an NFC tag, but I'm hoping since airplane mode is a universal function there may be some way of communicating directly with the user's device OS, sidestepping the requirement for an app to translate the function.

Is it possible to create an NFC tag that just works universally on its own? Is there another NFC editing app I should be using instead of Trigger, or a setting I have to tweak?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a common data format called NDEF (NFC Data Exchange Format).

You could store in NDEF message: text, URI, specific application data, ... but not action for android phone as enable/disable GPS, airplane mode, ...

So users need a specific app on their phones to do these kind of action.

Comment: Hmm okay not the answer I was hoping for but saves time investigating a futile approach! Maybe I can make a compromise with some kind of NDEF message.
Thanks!