# App-less Communication with NFC

Tags: android, nfc

I have been thinking of the Physical Web and how to go App-less. My question is that Does a smartphone or (an active NFC Reader) need an interface or app to send,receive and process data through Near Field Communication. Are there any other available options?

PS: Let me know if this question does not fit here, and where should I post it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read NFC tag without specific application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23546481/read-nfc-tag-without-specific-application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an Android-powered device scans an NFC tag containing NDEF formatted data, it parses the message and tries to figure out the data's MIME type or identifying URI. When the tag dispatch system is done creating an intent that encapsulates the NFC tag and its identifying information, it sends the intent to an interested application that filters for the intent. If more than one application can handle the intent, the Activity Chooser is presented so the user can select the Activity.

It there is no application that handle an intent - nothing will happen. You need an application in your device to use NFC tags.

Reference: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html

Comment: That's a fair point. But for identifying information like 'opening a URL in a browser' or ' turning on WiFi', doesn't Android handle it on its own? This site says it does not need an application which is the USP of NFC when compared to QR Codes. http://hubpages.com/technology/program-NFC-tags#

Comment: The tasks are defined in application, not in raw Android. Each phone that support NFC should have a app to handle the tags. In article you gave this application that knows what to do when tag will arrive is Trgger. First you define an action, then write ID to tag. After that when you put tag to your phone Trgger app will know how to handle the action for you. If you will not have Trgger app in other device this programmed tag will not work.

Comment: Yes I realized what you are saying after I watched the video. Thanks. I'd like to bother you again that is it not possible to program the NFC tag manually and code it somehow that NFC powered Android Phone can respond to it?

Comment: You can program the NFC manually with any data you want. There is few apps that supports writing business cards data to tag. If device has no NFC application sometimes Browser or Contacts app have support to read NDEF-formatted tags. Most cases if device supports NFC it should have NFC app bundled. But still it is application that can read url or vcard, not the Android system feature.

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot Fill. You have been great for giving me insights. I was thinking that since Android parses the data it might as well execute it. But anyway chrome beta has NFC feature I guess like you mentioned its the application. To-be-Native though. Thanks again.